# Android : Customize Zendesk Rate My APP UI

Tags: android, zendesk

How can I customize  rate my app dialog of Zendesk. In sample app a style is added in style.xml file and it is working. But I don't know how to apply that style for Rating dialog. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

style.xml:

```
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- Start rate my app dialogue styles -->
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->

    <style name="rma_button">
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_background</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
    </style>

    <style name="rma_title" parent="rma_button">
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
    </style>

    <style name="rma_divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1px</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider</item>
    </style>

    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- End rate my app dialogue styles -->
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- Start rate my app dialogue feedback styles -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->

    <style name="rma_feedback_issue_cancel_button" parent="_rma_feedback_issue_cancel_button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_gradient_btn</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_text</item>
    </style>

    <!--
        This style overrides the parent style to change the background colour of the button
        depending on the state
    -->
    <style name="rma_feedback_issue_send_button" parent="_rma_feedback_issue_send_button">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/green_gray_btn_selector</item> <!-- Button colour will change  -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_gray_txt_selector</item>
    </style>

    <style name="rma_feedback_message_title" parent="_rma_feedback_message_title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="rma_feedback_message_subtitle" parent="_rma_feedback_message_subtitle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_text</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
    </style>

    <!--
        In this example we are overriding the parent style using a selector to control the colour
        of the text differently whether the edittext is enabled or disabled.
    -->
    <style name="rma_feedback_issue_edittext" parent="_rma_feedback_issue_edittext">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/enabled_disabled_grey_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_hint</item>
    </style>


    <style name="rma_feedback_divider" parent="_rma_feedback_divider">
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider</item>
    </style>


    <style name="rma_feedback_progress" parent="_rma_feedback_progress">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_green_small_holo</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <!-- End rate my app dialogue feedback styles -->
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
```

Comment: rma_feedback styles are working for me. But not rma_button, rma_title, rma_divider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by creating a separate theme for the activity that is using RateMyApp dialog  and applied styles for button, title and divider of dialog as below

```
 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <item name="RateMyAppPaddingTop">@dimen/rma_padding_top</item>
        <item name="RateMyAppPaddingBottom">@dimen/rma_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="RateMyAppButtonStyle">@style/rma_button_style</item>
        <item name="RateMyAppTitleStyle">@style/rma_title_style</item>

        <item name="RateMyAppDividerStyle">@style/rma_divider_style</item>
        <item name="RateMyAppDividerHeight">@dimen/rma_divider_height</item>
    </style>


<dimen name="rma_padding_top">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="rma_padding_bottom">24dp</dimen>

<style name="rma_button_style">
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_background</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
    </style>
    <style name="rma_divider_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1px</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/divider</item>
    </style>
    <style name="rma_title_style" parent="rma_button">
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.25</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```